# Saddle point / Local Maxima

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

What I understand from the question is they're asking us what is $x = 3$ called, to which I'm answering a saddle point / critical point / stationary point. But  $x=3$ is also a local minimum for the function when we double differentiate and put the value.

What would be the appropriate answer to this question? Where am I going wrong with the understanding?
Please help

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3Gha.png)

[Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgyNG.png)

Comment: Picture is not a shortcut to typing text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are on correct track. It is a critical point associated with a minimum at $X=3$, but not an inflexion or saddle point, as can be checked employing its second derivative.

Answer (score 0):

There's no typo, it states that the value of the slope has value $0$ at $x=3$, i.e., $f'(3)=0$ which is true

$f'(x)=8x-24$

$f''(x)=8>0$ $\forall$ $x$

The second derivative is concave up at $x=3$, so it is a minimum